# Using many dictionaries within dictionaries in my code

Tags: c#, dictionary

I'm using a lot of dictionary collections that contain other dictionary collections like:

```
Dictionary<Guid, List<string>>()

Dictionary<Guid, Dictionary<Guid, List<string>>>()
```

I'm looping through these maps, and passing them around in parameters in my code.

This seems like a bad idea since you can't really extend the nature of these collections now.

Should I wrap these around in a class?

Comment: I think this is a code smell, but you deserve an upvote for that much self-awareness

Comment: is it allowed to say "Yo dawg.."? :p

Comment: @bertzzie: I thought of that myself, but cannot come up with a reasonably funny one as I'm too busy polishing my new diamond :)

Comment: Is a dictionary of dictionaries called a 2D dictionary?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you run into such limitations? Is your program hard to alter/debug? If so, refactor. Otherwise, profit: you're a pragmatic programmer,.

That said, I can see room for immediate improvement:

```
IDictionary<Guid, List<string>> x;

IDictionary<Guid, IDictionary<Guid, List<string>> y = new Dictionary<Guid, IDictionary<Guid, List<string>>();
```

Comment: It would be even better if I could give more meaning to Guid, like ProductID but I can't.

Comment: @codecompleting In that case, refactor :) Just aggregate a dictionary and have nice query methods with descriptive names. Not a lot of work, and you'll know when you are happy with it, just like you know _now_, that something is bothering you.

Answer (score 5):

I'd say yes, create a class specifically for it. Then you can add/not-implement methods as per your usage, rather than working around any limitations you find with `Dictionary` with your usage.

It sounds like you'd want a tree-like structure.

Answer (score 3):

At the least, wrap your "smelly" data structure in a class, so that you can encapsulate its implementation by providing a clean API to query/modify the data without any of the client code kowing anything about the storage details.

Then you will be free to change the implementation of the data structure at any time in the future. If you don't do this now, you may regret it later when you have 10 or 100 times as much client code, and it is too expensive/painful to refactor.

You may find that as long as you keep it encapsulated tidily, and it works, the fact that you feel it is smelly isn't really relevant - as long as code does what it needs to do and is maintainable, there is no point investing much more time into it. (I'm not advocating keeping dirty code, but we have to balance the commercial realities against our desire to achieve theoretical perfection - if code works and isn't causing any problems, then it may not always be a good use of your time to improve or refactor it. Instead, you may find that simply neutralising the risks by encapsulating it in a class and isolating the dirty implementation from its clients is sufficient for now)

Answer (score 2):

Because Dictionary type is a reference type, you're not in bad situation here, but just for code clarity consider defining a new type, derived from `Dictionary<Guid,List<string>>` just to shorten the code you're writing and to make it easy readable. The class should look like this:

```
internal class MyWrapper : Dictionary<Guid, List<string>>
{
}
```

Or if it's important for you to keep with `IDictionary`, then go on with composite design by wrapping a `Dictionary<Guid, List<string>>` instance into the class which implements the `IDictionary<Guid, List<string>>` and just delegates all the methods to the wrapped Dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

.NET 4.0 introduced Tuple, one even more abusable data structure, as nice as it seems in the beginning, as much pain it brings afterwards and should be used wisely.

Dictionary is somehow less evil here, because it serves for fast element access, not just as a glue instead of creating classes. I believe that there is nothing wrong with your usage of dictionaries if those dictionaries are used locally in a method for some calculation or something, but gets less clear when you start passing them around as parameters. If that is the case, I think you need to create a class for it.